# Como cambiar color input cuando cambia su valor en JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una funcion en javascript que cuenta caracteres y quisiera cambiar el color del texto del input cuando su valor desciende de por ejemplo, los 1200 caracteres.

Esto llevo de momento:

```js
function ocultarContador(){
   
  document.getElementById('ocultar').style.display = 'none';
}

function mostrarContador(){

  document.getElementById('ocultar').style.display = 'inline-block';

}

/*_CONTADOR DE CARACTERES_*/
  function cuenta(){ 
         
    var max = "1500";

    var cadena = document.getElementById("com").value; 
    var longitud = cadena.length; 
  
    if(longitud <= max){ 
      document.getElementById("contador").value = max-longitud; 
    } else { 
      document.getElementById("com").value = cadena.substr(0, max);
  }
                
    if (document.getElementById("contador").value < 1200) {

      document.getElementById("contador").style.color = "orange";
              
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("contador").value <= 1000) {

      document.getElementById("contador").style.color = "red";
               
    }
  }
```

```css
.ocultar{
  display: none;

}
.ocultar input{

  border-style: none;
  background-color: rgba(250,250,250,0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>¿En qué podemos ayudarte?</label>
  <br><br>
  <textarea cols="30" rows="10" name="comment" class="form-control" id="com" placeholder="Ingrese su mensaje aquí..." required="required" maxlength="1500" onfocus="mostrarContador(this)" onblur="ocultarContador(this)" onkeyup="cuenta()" onkeydown="cuenta()" title="Completa este campo"></textarea>
         
  <div id="ocultar" class="ocultar">
    <label style="color: black; font-size: 14px;">Caracteres Restantes:&nbsp;</label>
    <input disabled="disabled" maxlength="3" value="1500" id="contador"> 
  </div>
</div>
```

De momento funciona hasta el primer cambio, cuando desciende de los 1200 caracteres, pero no lo toma cuando desciende de los 1000, ahí debería cambiar a color rojo, el texto del input. ¿Que podré haber hecho mal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tienes los if invertidos, es decir, 1000 es más pequeño que 1200 y tu primer if es el de 1200. Por lo tanto nunca pasa más abajo.

Si cambias el primer if comparando los 1000 carácteres y depués pones el else if del 1200 funciona perfectamente.

```js
function ocultarContador(){
   
  document.getElementById('ocultar').style.display = 'none';
}

function mostrarContador(){

  document.getElementById('ocultar').style.display = 'inline-block';
}

/*_CONTADOR DE CARACTERES_*/
function cuenta(){ 

  var max = "1500";

      var cadena = document.getElementById("com").value; 
      var longitud = cadena.length; 

  if(longitud <= max){ 
    document.getElementById("contador").value = max-longitud; 
  } else { 
      document.getElementById("com").value = cadena.substr(0, max);
  }

  if (document.getElementById("contador").value < 1000) {

    document.getElementById("contador").style.color = "red";

  }
  else if (document.getElementById("contador").value <= 1200) {

    document.getElementById("contador").style.color = "orange";

  }
}
```

```css
.ocultar{
  display: none;

}
.ocultar input{

  border-style: none;
  background-color: rgba(250,250,250,0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
         <label>¿En qué podemos ayudarte?</label>
         <br><br>
           <textarea cols="30" rows="10" name="comment" class="form-control" id="com" placeholder="Ingrese su mensaje aquí..." required="required" maxlength="1500" onfocus="mostrarContador(this)" onblur="ocultarContador(this)" onkeyup="cuenta()" onkeydown="cuenta()" title="Completa este campo"></textarea>
         
         <div id="ocultar" class="ocultar">
                               <label style="color: black; font-size: 14px;">Caracteres Restantes:&nbsp;</label>
                               <input disabled="disabled" maxlength="3" value="1500" id="contador"> 
                        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Aah con que era eso, ya lo revise y funciona ahora, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás ejecutando en el primer `if` una condición que también se va a cumplir cuando es menor que 1000, por lo que deberís cambiar el orden de los `if`

```js
function ocultarContador(){
   
  document.getElementById('ocultar').style.display = 'none';
}

function mostrarContador(){

  document.getElementById('ocultar').style.display = 'inline-block';

}

/*_CONTADOR DE CARACTERES_*/
  function cuenta(){ 
         
    var max = "1500";

    var cadena = document.getElementById("com").value; 
    var longitud = cadena.length; 
  
    if(longitud <= max){ 
      document.getElementById("contador").value = max-longitud; 
    } else { 
      document.getElementById("com").value = cadena.substr(0, max);
  }
                
     if (document.getElementById("contador").value <= 1000) {

      document.getElementById("contador").style.color = "red";
               
    }
    
    else if (document.getElementById("contador").value < 1200) {

      document.getElementById("contador").style.color = "orange";
              
    }
    
  }
```

```css
.ocultar{
  display: none;

}
.ocultar input{

  border-style: none;
  background-color: rgba(250,250,250,0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>¿En qué podemos ayudarte?</label>
  <br><br>
  <textarea cols="30" rows="10" name="comment" class="form-control" id="com" placeholder="Ingrese su mensaje aquí..." required="required" maxlength="1500" onfocus="mostrarContador(this)" onblur="ocultarContador(this)" onkeyup="cuenta()" onkeydown="cuenta()" title="Completa este campo"></textarea>
         
  <div id="ocultar" class="ocultar">
    <label style="color: black; font-size: 14px;">Caracteres Restantes:&nbsp;</label>
    <input disabled="disabled" maxlength="3" value="1500" id="contador"> 
  </div>
</div>
```